# Inject Content into WebView Before Loading Url

Tags: android, webview

I have an app with a previously-existing, web-based registration process that I am trying to use inside a WebView. I need to add some style tags to the html in order to hide some elements for better displaying the content inside my app. I can get it to work on initial load, but I cannot figure out how to do it from one page to the next inside the WebView. Here is what I have working:

On initial load of the site, I am getting the raw html and appending `"<style>MY STYLES HERE<`/style>" to the string before calling

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, rawHtml, null, "UTF-8", url);
```

This works perfectly, but if a user clicks a link on the page and it loads another page into the WebView, then this code does not get called and the style tag is lost.

I assume I need to override "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" in the WebViewClient, but I don't know how to intercept the html from here. I thought I would try something like:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    String rawHtml = getRawHtml(url) + "<style>...</style>";
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, rawHtml, null, "UTF-8", url);
}
```

But this obviously sends it into an endless loop of intercepting the load to start a new load.

I have also tried overriding onPageFinished and doing:

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { ... })()");
```

which works, except that it waits until the entire page is loaded before executing. This causes the page to appear loaded with all of the UI elements in tact, and then all of the ones I am trying to hide suddenly disappear. My ultimate goal is to enhance the look and feel of the site on a mobile device, so this is not an option.

Is there something else I can do in "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" to inject style tags? Or if not, what else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this problem, and depending on the number of redirects, etc, we have not been able to make the injected JavaScript available all the time.

At minimum, you should use the `wv.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { ... })()");` approach, but call it in both onPageStarted() and onPageFinished().

Depending on the complexity of your pages, you might need to inject the JavaScript in onLoadResource() as well.

Comment: I tried onLoadResource and it appears to work, but it also is wiping out half of the content on the page that I do want. My code is wv.loadUrl("javascript:function() { document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += '<style>...</style>'; }()"); Do you know why it would be doing this?